# checking a line ahead while reading a file before created a new node

Tags: c++, file, storage

[file being read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYw0y.png)

[outPut of said file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b8kr.png)

I'm trying to read from a file and store its data in my linked-list. The problem I come across is that when I read a person's information that contains a second address my function only updates my linked list with data containing two addresses. note: when printing my link-list it is in reverse order because prepend each node. Notice how the bottom 5 print statements contain 1 address, those are the first 5 lines I retrieve from the file. As soon the function gets to the 6th line which contains two addresses it fails to update my list with data containing only 1 address. However, it continues to update my list two data containing 2 addresses.

```
void AddressBook::readFile(string fileName) {

    ifstream f(fileName);

    string firstName = "", lastName, phoneNumber, buildingNumber, street, city, state, zipCode, buildingNumber_2, street_2, city_2, state_2, zipCode_2, entry;
    bool twoAddr = false;

    if (!f.is_open()) { die("file not open"); }

    while (f >> entry) {
        if (isdigit(entry[0])) {
            buildingNumber_2 = entry;
            f >> street_2 >> city_2 >> state_2 >> zipCode_2;
            addEntry(Person(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, Address(buildingNumber, street, city, state, zipCode), Address(buildingNumber_2, street_2, city_2, state_2, zipCode_2)));
                twoAddr = true;
        }
        else {
            if (firstName != "" && !twoAddr) {
                addEntry(Person(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, Address(buildingNumber, street, city, state, zipCode)));
                twoAddr = false;
            }
            firstName = entry;
            f >> lastName >> phoneNumber >> buildingNumber >> street >> city >> state >> zipCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this algorithm:

```cpp
for (;;) {
  line = file.readline();
  if (is_person_line(line))
    addEntry(create_person(line));
  else if (is_address_only(line))
    entries[-1].add_address(create_address(line));
}
```

It should also make your code clearer.

Comment: but since I'm adding to the front of the linked list I can add an address

Comment: This is what's called "pseudo-code", the idea of a solution. Functions like `readline` and `create_person` should be implemented by you, and I know you know how to implement them because I see them in your code.

Comment: My apologies, I thought there may have been a way to pass an entire line to a class. I am putting it together right now. I'll comment again after.

Comment: It works but for some reason, my setter function doesn't update with the current address or my print function is displaying a copy from before

Comment: Getters use a copy so if you use a reference it fixes that problem. Thank you!